Выполнение запроса к базе данные с помощью LINQ и EF (GroupJoin, Include, Where)
Я правильно понимаю, что при выполнении этого запроса сначала будет выполнятся Join между InternalOrders и CrmUsers, а уже затем из получившегося списка compliments с помощью Where выбираются те элементы, в которых AdvancedInfo не пустая строка? Или EF неявно оптимизирует запрос при построении плана запроса?
Если EF не оптимизирует автоматически, то как можно оптимизировать вручную? Не хотелось бы выполнять Join для лишних строк.
Вообще, цель в том, чтобы выбрать не удалённые заказы за определённый период (таблица InternalOrders), сделанные пользователями у которых есть Remarks или/и CrmUserRemarks, (таблица CrmUsers)
var compliments = FusionContext.InternalOrders
.Where(x => !x.Deleted && x.CreateDateTime >= startDateTime.Date && x.CreateDateTime <= endDateTime.Date)
.GroupJoin(FusionContext.CrmUsers
    .Include(x => x.CrmUserRemarks),
    order => order.HolderId,
    user => user.HolderId,
    (order, user) => new { order, usergroup = user.DefaultIfEmpty() })
    .Select(compliment => new Compliment
    {
        OrderId = compliment.order.OrderId.ToInt(),
        OperatorName = compliment.order.Operator,
        Phone = compliment.order.PhoneNumber,
        GuestName = compliment.usergroup.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,
        AdvancedInfo = $"{compliment.usergroup.FirstOrDefault().Remarks}\n{string.Join('\n', compliment.usergroup.FirstOrDefault().CrmUserRemarks.Select(x => x.Name))}",
        ApplyTime = compliment.order.CreateDateTime.GetValueOrDefault(),
        ClientId = compliment.order.HolderId.GetValueOrDefault()
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AdvancedInfo.Trim())).ToList();


Вы можете без труда посмотреть что вам сделает EF путем вызова в конце запроса .ToQueryString(), это сформирует вам SQL запрос. Также вы можете подцепиться к логгированию и вывести его куда вам надо, смотря там как и что выполняет EF/

EF сгенерирует SQL и пошлёт его в БД. А уже планировщик БД будет оптимизировать запрос.

Тот код, что стоит до вызова AsEnumerable() выполнится в БД. Тот, что после - выполнится на клиенте.

Укажите используемую СУБД и точную версию EF.

@AlexanderPetrov MS SQL Server, EF 8.0.3
